# not able to select date from date picker

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have recorded selenium code for selecting date from date picker. While running the test case, the date picker pops up and highlights the selected date correctly. But the date is not selected. 
The code looks like:-

```
driver.findElement(By.id("imgStartDate")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[5]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[5]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[5]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[5]")).click();

// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
```

This exception appears in the recorded code only.I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0 jar.

Comment: It is hard to tell what your issue is without providing the HTML of the website, or screen shots to help illustrate what you are talking about. I would recommend reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help receive an answer from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Recording will not work for date picker... try this code.

```
try{
    WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object)));

    List<WebElement> rows = dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));  
    List<WebElement> columns = dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));  

    for (WebElement cell: columns){
        if (cell.getText().equals(data)){
            cell.findElement(By.linkText(data)).click();
            break; 
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+" -- Not able to select the date"+e.getMessage();
}
```